# mbtiles: Is it possible to draw some lines on offline mbtiles map

Tags: ios, mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles

I have an .mbtiles file and I am using it for offline map (iOS MapBox SDK). But my .mbtiles doesn't have enough data (just simple green rectangle). I want to draw some lines(roads) between points (I download it from my rest API). I found the solution to use `RMShape`, but I want to use already drawn map. I create my .mbtiles from osm and TileMill. Help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

WhirlyGlobe-Maply SDK can help you achieve this.

1. It has a mapview and a globe view which you implement on your viewcontroller.
2. Then you create a layer using your mbtile file as shown below:

   `let tileSource = MaplyMBTileSource(mbTiles: "your-mbtile-filename")`
3. You add this layer on the globe or map to display the tiles.
4. And using SDK's function like `addShapes()`, you can add, circles, vectors, labels, text and icons on the map/globe.

I tried adding lat and long lines programatically. Also tried adding some labels and spheres.
This is how it looks ->

[WhirlyGlobe-Maply using mbtile and drawing on top of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzjSd.jpg)